# putting file names in an array using os in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I want to create a program that will use `os` to make an `ls` of a directory and then put the files in a array. However, `ls` does not list the names one by one, so I am kind of stuck, because there's nothing constant by which I can tell when the next name starts.

Here is the actual code:

```
import os
cd = input("Change directory to:   ")

while cd != "x":
    os.chdir(cd)
    command = os.popen('ls')
    ls = command.read()
    print(ls)
    cd = input("Change directory to:   ")
    count = 0
    word = ""

for character in ls:
    while count == 0 :
        if character!= " ":
            count = 1
            word += character

        elif character == " ":
            print(word)
```

So the idea is that, when the program starts, it should ask you which directory you want to change to and then run `ls` on that directory. Then if you type back `x`, it should just print the first directory to the screen. However, as I said, it just prints the entire list.

Can anybody help me with this?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: oh, sorry, below cd = input("change directory to:  ") it should read:

Comment: that middel line is actuely part of the code... sorry, stack overflow missunderstood it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the already-ready-to-go [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) - it will get you everything that's in a directory - files and directories.

But if you want just the files, you could add the usage of [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
files = [file for file in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, file))]
```